# Click event not firing on dynamically added LinkButton

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a `LinkButton` that is created dynamically in `Load` and then added to a control that resides on the `Master` page. Here is the original code used to create the `LinkButton`:

```
LockUnlock = new LinkButton() { ID = "LockUnlock", Visible = false };
LockUnlock.Click += LockUnlock_Click;
```

Now, when I first dug into this problem I thought it might be related to the ASP.NET life cycle so I moved the code to an `override OnInit`, but that didn't fix it.

I then moved on to setting the `ID` because that's not being done. So I added this line:

```
LockUnlock.ID = "LockUnlock";
```

and I tried that in both `OnInit` and `Load` - no luck.

Then I thought, because I'm adding this to a custom control that is actually part of a `ContentPlaceHolder` I may need to make the `ID` static to get this to work, so I added this:

```
LockUnlock.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static;
```

I have only tried that in the `Load`, but no luck, and honestly if it's not working in `Load` it's almost certainly not going to change anything in `OnInit` - that was just my first move and really a hail Mary in a lot of ways.

Alright, so now I'm at the point where I feel like it's related to the fact that the `ResourceCenter` is a custom control that is added to a `ContentPlaceHolder` and thus the event, though it's **technically** hooked up, can't be fired because of the context of the `class`. But I'm not sure where to go from here.

Do I need to add a shared class for the click? Do I need to hookup the click in the custom control and then delegate it from there somehow?

I would **prefer** *not* to use either of those solutions, but hey, we do what we have to do! I look forward to everybody's input on this.

## EDIT

The code that adds the control to the `ResourceCenter` looks like this:

```
this.ResourceCenter.AddAdminLink(LockUnlock.Visible ? LockUnlock : null);
```

and the code inside the `ResourceCenter` control that adds to its list looks like this:

```
if (link == null) { return; }

var wrapper = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
wrapper.Controls.Add(link);

this.AdminLinkList.Controls.Add(wrapper);
```

where `link` is what was passed into the method by the aforementioned line.

Comment: Can you share the code that adds the control to the page?

Comment: In Which page_load event you are adding controls master page or content page?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud, seems like control is never added. You initially set `Visible` to false, and then, when adding, checking for it. `LockUnlock.Visible ? LockUnlock : null` results to null, and nothing is added.

Comment: @Andrei, later on in the load it determines if it needs to be `Visible` and it's set to `true` and thus added. That's how I'm clicking on it. I just left that set of code out.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud, I am almost certain that this decision code is relevant here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would have to be in the init.  Also, try adding the control to the control's collection, before adding the event, as in:

```
LockUnlock = new LinkButton() { ID = "LockUnlock", Visible = false };
Panel.Controls.Add(LockUnlock);
LockUnlock.Click += LockUnlock_Click;
```